# How do I use another function/multiple functions inside of an Express route in order to manipulate data from a database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am working with Express and MySQL and I would like to be able to retrieve data from a `connection.query` and then use that data in other functions within the same route. I would like to be able to use the array made inside of the `connection.query` inside of another function in app.post, however I don't know what the best way to go about doing this is. I have tried to use utility functions written in a separate file required by Express but I haven't been able to get data from the MySQL connection into the function written in the external file and I'm not even sure if that's the proper way to do what I want.

Here is my code, what I'd like to do is possibly be able to put the `forEach` method inside of its own function and then use the returned array in another function after the query to do something with it and so on.

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
  var getPosition = "SELECT ID, position FROM routes";
  var posArray = [];
  connection.query(getPosition, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    results.forEach(function(item) {
      posArray.push(item.position);
      return posArray;
    }); //end if
  });
}); // end app.post
```

Comment: Your `return` is meaningless.

Comment: You need to use callbacks or promises.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain middleware to achieve this:

```
app.post('/submit', getDataFromDatabase, processData); // end app.post

function getDataFromDatabase(req, res, next) {
  var getPosition = "SELECT ID, position FROM routes";
  var posArray = [];
  connection.query(getPosition, function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    results.forEach(function(item) {
      posArray.push(item.position);
      req.posArray = posArray;  //attach the data that you want to use later to your req object
    }); //end if

    next(); //Call the next middleware;
  });
}

function processData(req, res, next){
    //Do whatever you want with req.posArray;

    res.json(posArray);  //respond to the client with the posArray (or whatever the client asked for)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it okay to include these middleware inside the server but outside of the app.get/app.post methods like you have demonstrated?

Comment: yes it is. They will behave the same as inline functions but are a lot easier to read.